# Where to set MembershipPassword() requirments?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-membership

The selected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281294/places-you-can-add-password-validation-in-mvc) shows one method of how the requirments can be set but I am looking to make those rules more reusable while still using the MembeshipPassowrd() validation attribute and I think it can be done by specifying the roles within my extended membership provider but I can't find any documentation on how this can be done.

How do I include the password requirments within my custom/extended membership provider?

**Model**

```
[Required]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[MembershipPassword(
    MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters = 1,
    MinNonAlphanumericCharactersError = "Your password needs to contain at least one symbol (!, @, #, etc).",
    ErrorMessage = "Your password must be 6 characters long and contain at least one symbol (!, @, #, etc)."
)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "New password")]
public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the PasswordStrngthRegularExpression is what is required to do this, it can either be set in the web.config file or within the extended membership provider by overriding it:

```
public override string PasswordStrengthRegularExpression
{
    get { return @"(?=.{5,})(?=(.*\d){1,})(?=(.*\W){1,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])"; }
}
```

**OR**

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider"
  userIsOnlineTimeWindow = "20>
  <providers>
    <add
      name="SqlProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
      connectionStringName="SqlServices"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
      passwordStrengthRegularExpression="@\"(?=.{6,})(?=(.*\d){1,})(?=(.*\W){1,})"
      />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.passwordstrengthregularexpression(v=vs.110).aspx) Has details on this.